# Floating block adds extra top margin

Tags: html, css, margin

I have this really simple code:

```css
header {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
aside {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
section {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<header>
  one
</header>
<main>
  <aside>sdf</aside>
  <section>
    <p>fd</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

The problem is that as I get extra `margin` between `header` and `main` tags. I have discovered that `p` tag makes this. After removing `p` tag there is no extra `margin`.

You can see jsfiddle [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/zh2ufbuj/).

[image]

I assume here is something connected with `line-break` that `p` tag adds.

Further more if I add this css:

```css
main {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I get event more strange result. what is the reason for that?

[image]

Comment: what is the desired look of your page ?

Comment: Do a search for the difference between inline elements and block elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p`by default has `margin-block-end: 1em;margin-block-start: 1em;` so just reset it

```css
header {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
aside {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
section {
  background-color: orange;
}
p {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<header>
  one
</header>
<main>
  <aside>sdf</aside>
  <section>
    <p>fd</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

By default HTML page have some body `margin` in it. So you simply put `margin:0px;`

```
body{
margin:0px;
}
```